# I’m stuck in “try ubuntu without installing” and can’t access windows anymore

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I have a dual-boot system with windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04. After I restart my computer it’s passed in ubuntu automatically, and there’s not any option to go to windows . 
The only options are: 
*Try ubuntu without installing
Install ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers) 
Check disc for defects

I’m stuck in “trying to use ubuntu without installing”. I’m not trying to Install Ubuntu because I’m afraid something can go wrong . So is better for me to delete ubuntu and return to windows , but I don’t know how ‍♀️ 
Please help me

Comment: An installed Ubuntu won't have a 'Try Ubuntu' option, so it sounds like your machine is booting a 'live' system (such as Ubuntu install media) rather than your normal hdd/ssd.  This will be changed by a machine specific function and we don't know what you're using (this isn't a hardware support site either), but why tag 14.04?

Comment: If you already installed Ubuntu, then you did it the wrong way...so you are wise to be concerned about making another mistake. If you have not already installed Ubuntu, then simply remove the Installer LiveUSB stick.

Comment: Yeah, power off and remove the USB or eject the disk and then power back on.

Comment: If you have made the installer DVD/USB that it seems like you using, the 'try ubuntu option is very safe and you can use ubuntu without it messing with your computer.  That option is for people to check out their hardware and to see if they like Ubuntu.  It does not save any changes or downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Try Ubuntu 18.04 and you will have the power off option in the corner. Just select it and remove the USB then restart.
If you are trying to update ubuntu from 14.04 to 18.04 this may be helpful:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start[enter link description here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start)

Comment: This was helpful thank u so much !!! 
Yesterday I tried to turn off my pc and then to remove the usb , but was not  the correct 
Now is ok